# DisplayTables vs dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, jsp-tags, displaytag

we can generate a table viz(java(as JSP tags)) and javascript (jquery and other Js plugins)

but the question is on what parameters one should decide whether the table should be generated in java or using a Js library + scriptlets.

i think using javascript plugin could be problematic if the number of rows in huge lets say (10k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with DisplayTables ,

But...

If you talking about http://datatables.net/ and you about to deal with 10k rows you better use its full server side configuration

I started with pure client side then moved to client side + JSON from server , and ended using  full server side processing cause i had to deal with thousands of records...

here a link

[DataTables server-side processing example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)